# How to bind JavaScript events to entry form fields in the control panel

Tags: craft3, entries-field, frontend, entry-form

When adding an entry, there is a field called resource id, I want to build a front end event on this field, after the value input or changed, trigger ajax to call an external api to check whether the resource id is existing.

I wonder if there is a way to do that, many thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by frontend event? A frontend form that updates the value of that field?

Comment: @MoritzLost such as onChange event. when the value changed, will trigger that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to build a custom plugin to do this you can easily add JavaScript to the control panel using the CP-JS plugin: https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-js